# sharepoint development and visual studio express

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2012, express

I recently started an internship and for my time here I will be working on the company's Intranet using sharepoint. I am still waiting for the exact details so I was planning on prepping myself with an understanding of Sharepoint. I know a few things they would like so I was going to get a head start on them. I decided to follow some walkthroughs on MSDN but I noticed that Visual Studio 2012 express lacks an option for sharepoint projects.

So my question is, is there a way to get this option or is it impossible with Visual Studio Express?

Comment: What version of SharePoint will you be using? For 2013 I would look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj164084.aspx

Comment: First thing I'd do is look for any sharepoint sdks on MSDN and download the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Express no but the company your with should have at least Visual Studio 2010(maybe 2013). Both those editions are sharepoint friendly.